# EditText Not Reading Input in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

The problem in EditText is, it is not returning the input value.I am using that input value to check condition.

I am giving the correct input so that i checks the if condition and go to next activity but
it always goes to else condition.

Please check the code below, i had commented the problem.

Here is the snippet

```
public class BuildWord extends Activity
{
String word = "word";
String finished = "Word Built";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buildword);

    EditText get = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataToSend);
    String getdata = get.getText().toString(); //Here i am getting Data from EditText

    displayIntentData();

    if (getdata.equals("word")) 

    //Here i am checking with "word" but it goes to else condition.I am typing "word" only
    {
        findViewById(R.id.sendButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BuildWord.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", word);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        findViewById(R.id.sendButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BuildWord.this,DropCard.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", finished);
                startActivity(intent);                  
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    displayIntentData();
}

private void displayIntentData()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.intentData1);
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();

    if(extras!=null)
    {
        tv.setText("Data received: "+extras.getString("key"));
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setText("No extradata received");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post buildword.xml?  What value do you get in `getdata`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  displayIntentData(); declare  String getdata = get.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the value in the EditText field ("get") immediately after inflating the view. you couldn't have time to enter any text yet, so it is empty. you then check if "getData" contains "word" (it doesn't!) therefore you're hitting the ELSE.

Comment: Thanks David sir, when i debug the application what you mentioned is happened.Now i got answer.

Comment: And also please clear my doubts and design.i had posted link here. My question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329356/android-database-design-for-multiplayer-card-game

Answer (score 0):

We will get the text when any click event is happened ....

```
String getdata = get.getText().toString(); //Here i am getting Data from EditText
```

above code always return empty string ...

try put the code in on click event and process so that you can get the string and compare it easily

Answer (score 0):

You are getting input data right after when the view is being created.
Instead try to take input data inside your click listener